# How to format a JQuery GetJSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fullcalendar

I'm calling the server with:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetWhoBowls", "Home")';
 $.getJSON(url, { "theDate": "calEvent.start" }, function (data) {
                    alert(data.name);
                });
```

I've tried all  permutation of quoting the 'theDate' and even calEvent.start as above .... in all cases the server complains that (from Firebug):

> > The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'theDate' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetWhoBowls(Double)' in 'MatchClubMVC.Controllers.HomeController'.

Firebug shows the parameters of the call as
theDate calEvent.start

Here is my controller method signature

public ActionResult GetWhoBowls(double theDate)

Could someone be so kind as to set me on the correct path?!

Comment: What value is passed along by calEvent.start? (I am unfamiliar with fullcalendar)

Comment: Major Byte,  the calEvent.start is the starting Date and Time of the clicked event.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect a double on your controller don't send a string (remove the simple quotes around `calEvent.start` otherwise you are sending this string literal to the server which obviously cannot be converted to double):

```
$.getJSON(url, { theDate: calEvent.start }, function (data) {
    alert(data.name);
});
```

Also make sure that `calEvent.start` is a valid double value.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public ActionResult GetWhoBowls(double? theDate)
```

also the error is arising because you are sending a null value in `{ "theDate": "calEvent.start" }`

**EDIT**

not sure whether this will solve the problem or not but try this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetWhoBowls", "Home")';
 $.getJSON(url, { theDate: "calEvent.start" }, function (data) {
                    alert(data.name);
                });
```

and modify the action result like this

```
public ActionResult GetWhoBowls(double theDate)
{
  return(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this will give the same errorif you send null from client

Comment: Why is the controller receiving a null when I can see that calEvent.start is a valid date on the client?  Making the type a nullable double now allows the parameter to come in.  My question is HOW do a pass the calEvent.start as parameter in the JSON call.  Obviously what I'm doing is not correct

Comment: @Paul Stocks you question was why receiving the error `:)` anyway i'll update the question in a moment

Comment: i hope its not the case of type mismatch if you are passing `DateTime` from client, at server you'll have to do `DateTime theDate`

Comment: quoting the calEvent.start doesn't help  FireBug shows the parameters as theDate : calEvent.start.   I'm expecting the date object to be serialized into a double as this is what I get with EventSources from FullCalendar where the plugin sends me start and end dates as doubles.   thanks for your help

Comment: add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as you second parameter to the return